# Is there a way/app to automatically change DNS server based on connection?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, automation, dns

Let say on my home Wifi, I want to use DNS server "X" and on work WiFI, I want to use another DNS-server: "Y", on cellular a server "Z" and so on.
Is this possible to do this automatically? (Preferably without root)
There seems to be loads of "DNS-apps" on play store, but I can't find any that do this. (have not tried them all)

Comment: If you disable the "private DNS" feature of Android you should get the matching DNS server for each connection automatically pushed as part of the IP information via DHCP.

Comment: I don't see how this helps? I know what DNS servers I want to use.

Comment: So you don't want the standard DNS servers, but use special other DNS servers but for each connection a different one. That was not obvious from your question.

Comment: Exactly..I really tried to be as clear as possible but I guess I wasn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution below will set Private DNS to "Automatic" on SSID: 'SSID-1'  and 'SSID-2' Everything else will set Private DNS to your entered Private DNS hostname in settings.

1. Install [Tasker.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=sv&gl=US)
2. Set up tasker as [follow](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/9yvo2h/android_p_private_dns_setting_access_in_tasker/):  (Change SSID-1/SSID2 to your name)

   ```
    Profile: AutoPrivateDNS
            State: Wifi Connected [ SSID:SSID-1/SSID-2 MAC:* IP:* Active:Any ]
        Enter: Anon
            A1: Custom Setting [ Type:Global Name:private_dns_mode Value:opportunistic Use Root:Off Read Setting To: ]
        Exit: Anon
            A1: Custom Setting [ Type:Global Name:private_dns_mode Value:hostname Use Root:Off Read Setting To: ]
   ```
3. Grant Tasker WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permissions via ADB with following command:

`adb shell pm grant net.dinglisch.android.taskerm android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`

4. To set Private DNS to Off instead of 'Automatic' use the value 'Off' instead of 'opportunistic'.
5. Tested with Android 11, Samsung S10E, no root.

Comment: Two updates for Tasker 6.1.32 with Android 13 on Pixel 7 Pro. First when it says `Value:hostname` above, that is literal. I thought it meant the desired hostname, so I used `dns.adguard.com` and it didn't work.  Second, if you want to use mode `off` instead of `opportunistic` note that it is case sensitive.  The text above suggests `Off`, but `off` is required to actually select the off state.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a Tasker profile that is based on either a location or a WiFi network to trigger the task. Set the task to change the custom setting for private DNS with the hostname dependent on which network you are on.

Comment: Thanks, This worked fine! I posted a more detailed answer below how to do it.